# Performance: iterate over an array except for an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, performance, indexing

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to iterate over an array of objects (class istances) except for the element with `id` equal to `1` (the `id` refers to the array[`1`] index).

I know that I can use an `if` statement "internally" to an `each` statement and doing that I check for each "current"\"considered" element `if id == 1`. However, since the array is populated of a lot of data, I would like to find another way in order to accomplish the same things in a more performant way (avoiding to run the `if` each time).

**How can I do?**

Comment: Why not ensure the array is not populated with the id of 1 to begin with?

Comment: why there is no array.except element method in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a.each_with_index.reject {|el,i| i == 1}.each do |el,i|
  # do whatever with the element
  puts el
end
```

Is IMHO a better way of doing the selection instead of using your own explicit `if` statement.  I believe, however, that it will result in approximately the same performance as using `if`, maybe even slightly lower.

If after benchmarking as others have suggested you know that the time this takes is definitely slower than what you can allow it, and it is the selection causing the slowness then this can be easily modified to remove the selection in a number of ways:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
n = 1
(a.first(n) + a.drop(n + 1)).each do |el|
  # do whatever with the element
  puts el
end
```

Unfortunately I believe this will also be slower than running the simple if.   One that I believe might have the potential for speed is:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
n = 1
((0...n).to_a+((n+1)...a.size).to_a).map{|i| a[i]}.each do |el|
  # do whatever with the element
  puts el
end
```

But this again has a high possibility of being slower.

**EDIT**

Benchmark is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1039348).  These results actually surprised me, reject is by far the slowest option, followed by the ranges.  The highest performing after not removing the element at all was using `first` and `drop` to select all the elements around it.

The results as a percentage using no selection as a baseline:

```
with if             146%
with first and drop 104%
without if          100%
```

Obviously this is highly dependant on what you do with the elements, this was testing with probably the fastest operation Ruby can perform.  The slower the operation the less difference these will have.  As always: **Benchmark, Benchmark, Benchmark**

Answer (score 8):

1. Make program work
2. Profile
3. Optimize

[Donald Knuth said:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

> We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil.

Now, you *could* do something like:

```
def f
  do_something
end

f 0
for i in 2..n
  f i
end
```

Or even:

```
def f
  yield 0
  for i in 2..@n
    yield i
  end
end

f do |i|
  do_something
end
```

But you probably do not *want* to do anything of the sort, and if you did, it would only be after finding out that it matters.

And finally, suppose this ugly trick actually makes your server run ever so slightly faster. Was it worth it?

Comment: +1, exactly what I was about to say. `if id == 1` is generally going to be very performant. Don't sweat it unless you discover actual performance problems down the road, then fire up your profiler.

Answer (score 1):

`if` statement is a very cheap operation. You can check that using standard benchmarking tools.

```
require "benchmark"

array = [1] * 100_000

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report "with if" do
    array.each_with_index do |element, i|
      next if i == 1
      element - 1
    end
  end

  bm.report "without if" do
    array.each do |element|
      element - 1
    end
  end
end
```

Results:

```
                user     system      total        real
with if     0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.018115)
without if  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.012248)
```

It is about 0.006 second difference on a 100 000 elements array. You shouldn't care about that unless it becomes a bottleneck and I doubt it will.

Answer (score 1):

Testing an actual for loop might be worth the five minutes it would take. It may be frowned on in Ruby circles, but that doesn't mean it is not ever worth using. When you call each or map or whatever, those methods use for loops any way. Avoid absolutes.

It also depends how big the array can get, at some n, one might become faster than the other. In this case, it is definitely not worth it.

If you don't need a specific element, maybe you don't need to store that row of data in a database. What is the difference between row 1 and the rest of the rows, in other words, why are you skipping it? Is the row with id=1 always going to have the the same data in it? If so, storing it as a constant would likely be better, and would make your question moot. Performance almost always costs more memory.

Unless Rails 3 does things differently, and you pull out the data and use id as the finder key, id=1 will be in element 0.

Unfortunately, Knuth's quote gets misinterpreted a lot and get used to excuse crappy, inefficient code that would not be written if the programmer was sufficiently educated, and thought about it for 5 seconds. Sure, spending a week trying to speed up code that you don't know is a problem or is a minor problem but this is more what Knuth was talking about. Performance is one of the most misunderstood and abused concepts in computer science.